# is joomla secure if i do the following:

Tags: php, security, content-management-system, joomla

is joomla secure if i:

- use su_php to run php in cgi mode
- lock down all component folders other than com_content and images (only necessary folders)
- do not allow 3rd party plugins
- do not allow frontend login
- keep admin login behind a htaccess password
- change default usetname admin to xxxxxx.admin
- change default db prefix from jos_ to xxx__

obsviously to secure mysql and linux to a good standard

Is there anything im missing?

Cheers

Ke

Comment: No. Joomla, like most complex software, is going to have bugs, some of them security related. For example, http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5199-joomla-156-released.html

Answer (score 1):

The ONLY way for YOU to know for sure will be to conduct a thorough code analysis.

Next, search google for "joomla sql injection" and decide for yourself if it's worth it. (Here's one hit: http://www.packtpub.com/article/preventing-sql-injection-attacks-on-joomla-websites )

Answer (score 0):

change default usetname admin to xxxxxx.admin
change default db prefix from jos_ to xxx__
do not allow 3rd party plugins
do not allow frontend login

The above 4 are obviously possible and secure with Joomla, others I am not sure.